# c# Directory.CreateDirectory( path ), Should I check if path exists first?

Tags: c#, file, directory

I need to copy some files into a directory, but sometimes that directory doesn't already exist and has to be created first. Most of the time the directory will exist though, as it only has to be created once.

I know that I can just put `Directory.CreateDirectory()` before the file copy and `CreateDirectory()` will just return if the directory already exists.

```
string destFolder; // path to destination
string sourceFolder; // path to source
Directory.CreateDirectory( destFolder ); // this will work even if destFolder exists
File.Copy( sourceFolder + sourceFileName, destFolder + sourceFileName );
```

But I know that in almost every case the destination folder will already exist, so is it faster to check if it exists first, rather than calling `CreateDirectory()` anyway.

```
if( !Directory.Exists( destFolder ) ) // check if it exists first
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory( destFolder );
}
// now move on to using the folder
```

I don't really care how long it takes to create the directory considering that users will only ever do it once. I'm more interested in whether or not the `if` statement with `Directory.Exists()` is any faster than the time it takes for `Directory.CreateDirectory()` to figure out that the directory already exists.

It "feels" wasteful to me to call `Directory.CreateDirectory()` every time even though it probably exists, so I "feel better" checking first, but it's still a function call either way so am I really even getting an advantage by uglying-up my code with extra `if` statements and `Directory.Exists()` checks?

Comment: @TOby Because the API he's calling already does it - and it's documented that it does that check, so there's no point.

Comment: @Toby Also I have to do it about 12 times (gotta copy a bunch of files into a bunch of different folders that have to potentially be made) so it adds about 40 lines of technically unnecessary code for possibly not even any performance benefit.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can check the code of the [Directory](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,b3ad5f0ba800bb28) class out in the Microsoft Reference source. The first thing `Directory.CreateDirectory` does is call `Directory.Exists` (or the internal equivalent, [InternalExists](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,f6a0a4f50ba5376e)). So using the two methods you are kind of writing this:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
    }
}
```

Personally I would never do the `Exists` check.

Comment: Ah thank you. This was the kind of answer I was looking for. I don't know about `CreateDirectory`'s internal structure and this really puts into perspective how pointless and redundant it is to check if the directory exists externally.

Comment: It's unfortunate that MSDN's main example of CreateDirectory first calls Directory.Exists and does not mention this tidbit.  Good to know.

Answer (score 7):

There is no reason to check for existence first.  `Directory.CreateDirectory` already handles that case for you.  From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path **unless they already exist**.

(emphasis mine)

The work done internally will be about the same - but if it does *not* exist, you're checking twice, which slows things down, as `Directory.Exists` has to do all of the same internal normalization.  For details, see the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,234).

Answer (score -3):

You should definitely go for calling `Directory.Exists()` first to check if that folder exists, and then calling the `Directory.CreateDirectory()` only if it doesn't. It's not uglying the code, it's the right practice to follow.

And regarding what runs faster, you can use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class to compare the time spent on the `CreateDirectory()` version and the `if (Directory.Exists(...))` version. The difference will be very small in the case if the directory already exists and you shouldn't care about it as you will gain nothing in performance by optimising such things.

Comment: As was explained in answers above, the statement in your answer are untrue.